# Company name next to website URL

Tags: seo, google-search

Anyone knows how do I show the company name next to my URL in Google search results? I am not talking about Google authorship, I do not even know what this thing is called or how to even go about it so if anyone has any idea.

Look at the image to know what I am talking about.

[image: Google search results]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: See http://www.schema.org/

Answer (score 0):

In Google I dont't see the arrows and brand names you are talking about. But the following document seems usefull to me:
http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/nl//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

Comment: Useful to you but totally unrelated and not at all helpful.

Just google "how to cook" and look at the top two results, they have this company name thing next to them. Google started doing this couple months ago and i would love to know how to do this.

Comment: Ahh now I see, well it seems it is all information from wikipedia, maybe creating a wikipedia page about your company helps. Google itself says this:
http://insidesearch.blogspot.com.au/2014/01/more-information-about-websites-to-help.html